# UITableView list not displaying all items

Tags: uitableview, ios4

In my UITableView I am trying to display all the items in my plist but its not showing all the items. Actually it is showing most of it but the lower items are being repeated for some odd reason. I basically want to show all the keys in the plist with their respective values. Is the list too long to display? there's about 30 items.

First I tried to sort the keys and thought that was the problem, so then I didn't sort at all and I get the same problem, lower down the list the items get repeated and not showing the last 3 items. Is there a limit?

Below is some code, I've just modified to fit:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"PreferencesCell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"PreferencesCell2";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier3 = @"PreferencesCell3";

    UITableViewCell *cell;     

    NSArray *keys = [[[preferences objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Rows"] allKeys];
    NSString *prefName = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 2) {

        if(indexPath.section == 0)
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        else if(indexPath.section == 2)
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        if (cell == nil) {

            if(indexPath.section == 0)
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
            else if(indexPath.section == 2)
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 31);
            UILabel *settingName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
            settingName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
            settingName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            settingName.text = prefName;


            [cell.contentView addSubview: settingName];
            [settingName release];

        }

    } else if(indexPath.section == 1) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier3];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier3] autorelease];

            CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 31);
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
            label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            label.text = prefName;

            [cell.contentView addSubview: label];
        }

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    } 

    return cell;
}
```

What I've found is that if I don't use the labels and just go for the generic cell.textLabel.text approach then all the items are displayed correctly. However if I use the UILabel approach, the bottom items are not shown. I need to go this route as I'm adding other items in the Cell.

Working Code.

Initialization and creation of cell must be created first, then using that referenced cell remove from superview, then render the subviews. So reordering of the code from above.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"PreferencesCell1";
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"PreferencesCell2";
        static NSString *CellIdentifier3 = @"PreferencesCell3";

        UITableViewCell *cell;     

        NSArray *keys = [[[preferences objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Rows"] allKeys];
        NSString *prefName = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Create/Initialize Cell first

        if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 2) {

            if(indexPath.section == 0)
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
            else if(indexPath.section == 2)
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

            if (cell == nil) {

                if(indexPath.section == 0)
                    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
                else if(indexPath.section == 2)
                    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];   
            }

        } else if(indexPath.section == 1) {

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier3];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier3] autorelease];
            }
        } 

        // remove from superview

        [cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

        // render the subviews

        if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 2) {

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 31);
            UILabel *settingName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
            settingName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
            settingName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            settingName.text = prefName;


            [cell.contentView addSubview: settingName];
            [settingName release];

        } else if(indexPath.section == 1) {

            CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 31);
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
            label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            label.text = prefName;

            [cell.contentView addSubview: label];

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the numberOfRowsInSection callback method?

Comment: I've added that code in, the section numbers are correct and so to the number of rows in section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like cells are being reused and you are just adding new views to their existing contents. You need to reset the content, as described here: [UITbleViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you were just setting the cell's `textLabel` each time, setting a new value would suffice here, but if you are adding subviews you may need something more like `[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Comment: this is just what I needed. I re-ordered my code to create the cell initially as it got confused what to remove, then I added in the removeFromSuperView after the cell was initialised and then I rendered the subviews again. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Limit for a Tableview is the free RAM size.

Please post some Code. But i think that this could be a Problem with Cell caching.

Comment: I've added some code, I think it might be cell caching but I dont know how to remove the caching or how to refresh it?